# Replace UpdatePanel with JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-ajax, .net-2.0, updatepanel

I'm using UpdatePanel to asynchronously call a button click event in a page that calls a method in another class which writes out an XML file on the output. Is there a way to do this with JQuery instead of UpdatePanel?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use jQuery to handle the click event. Then call a page method in the code-behind using [this technique](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/). From there you can write the XML file or do whatever else you want.

Answer (score 3):

A simple alternative way to using jQuery to do ajax without the update panel is to use a build in mechanism of ASP.NET called 'page methods'. By decorating a static method in the page behind with `[WebMethod]` the web site will have a generated javascript function you can call using `PageMethods.MethodName(param1, param2)`. You will still need to include a ScriptManager control and enable page methods like this:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="theScriptManager" runat="server"
    EnablePageMethods="true" />
```

For more information you can search for 'Page Methods ASP.NET AJAX'.

Hope this helps

Comment: If doing it with jQuery, you don't need ScriptManager. That's the nice thing. You don't have the extra bloat of using both frameworks.

Answer (score -2):

To call a button click event in jquery you can do this...

```
$("#MyButtonID").click();
```

Where the button html looks like this...

```
<input type="button" id="MyButtonID" value="Press Me" />
```